# Problems with multi-thread iOS KVO process

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, progress-bar, key-value-observing

Having a problem transferring a KVO process from macOS to iOS.

In the Mac program, the user fills out a screen and then presses a ‘go’ button which submits a background task and starts a new window.  The new window uses KVO to get a stream of status messages from the background task and display them to the screen.

In the iOS program, I’m trying to do a similar process to light up a progress bar as well as capture some status info.  The program segues into a fresh storyboard panel with just a progress bar (for now) and a done button.  The storyboard panel appears and the ‘viewDidAppear’ method executes which initiates the background task.  The background task runs but the observeValueForKeyPath: method never fires off.  I’m wondering if I’m having some sort of threading complication somewhere.

The window is not a popover.  It was named that way and changed to a regular storyboard 'show' type panel.

When the original ‘go’ button is pressed, the following code is executed:

```
-(IBAction)clearCloudDB:(id)sender {

    ClearCloudDBClass* tempClearCloudDBClass = [[ClearCloudDBClass alloc] init];
    savedClearCloudDBClass = tempClearCloudDBClass;
    tempClearCloudDBClass.localFindItDataController = self.localFindItDataController;

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"clearPopover" sender: self];


}
```

The segue code follows here:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"backupPopover"]) {
    BackupPopover *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    vc.popoverPresentationController.delegate = nil;}

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"clearPopover"]) {
    ClearPopover *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

    vc.localSecondViewController = self;
    vc.localClearCloudDBClass = savedClearCloudDBClass;}

}
```

Here is the background process class h file:

```
@class ClearPopover;

@interface ClearCloudDBClass : NSObject {

NSInteger iteration_counter;
NSInteger total_counter;

FindItDataController* localFindItDataController;
ClearPopover* localClearPopover;

}

 @property NSInteger iteration_counter;
@property NSInteger total_counter;
@property FindItDataController *localFindItDataController;
@property ClearPopover *localClearPopover;


- (void) ClearCloudDBClassRun:(id) parameterTestFinditAppDelegate;

@end
```

Here is the background process class m file.  Please excuse the incomplete iCloud coding.  Not trapping errors for now:

```
#import "ClearCloudDBClass.h"
#import "Item.h"

@implementation ClearCloudDBClass

@synthesize iteration_counter, total_counter, localFindItDataController,     localClearPopover;

- (void) ClearCloudDBClassRun:(NSObject *) parameterTestFinditCaller {

dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Background Queue",NULL);

dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *nsarrayFetchedObjects;
    Item *tempItem;
    total_counter = 0;
    iteration_counter = 0;

    NSFetchRequest *totalcountfetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription1 = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item"  inManagedObjectContext: localFindItDataController.managedObjectContext];
    [totalcountfetch setEntity:entityDescription1];
    NSUInteger reccount =
        [localFindItDataController.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:totalcountfetch error:&error];
    total_counter = (int)reccount;

    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item"  inManagedObjectContext: localFindItDataController.managedObjectContext];
    [fetch setEntity:entityDescription];
    [fetch setFetchLimit:1];

    nsarrayFetchedObjects = [localFindItDataController.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

    while ([nsarrayFetchedObjects count] != 0) {
        tempItem = [nsarrayFetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        [localFindItDataController.managedObjectContext deleteObject:tempItem];
        nsarrayFetchedObjects = [localFindItDataController.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
        [localFindItDataController.managedObjectContext save:&error];
        iteration_counter++;}

    iteration_counter = total_counter;

});

}
```

Finally, here is the KVO code in the view controller.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[localClearCloudDBClass addObserver:self
                         forKeyPath:@"iteration_counter"
                            options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                            context:NULL];

[localClearCloudDBClass addObserver:self
                         forKeyPath:@"total_counter"
                            options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                            context:NULL];

progressBar.progress = 0.00;

[localClearCloudDBClass ClearCloudDBClassRun:self];

}
```

This process may might have a some bug in it but I can’t get it to fire off  at all:

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change
context:(void *)context
{

[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

    NSLog(@"keyPath %@", keyPath);

    int iteration_counter;
    int total_counter;

    iteration_counter = (int) localClearCloudDBClass.iteration_counter;
    total_counter = (int) localClearCloudDBClass.total_counter;

    if (total_counter != 0) {
        progressBar.progress = (float) iteration_counter / (float) total_counter;}
    else {
        progressBar.progress = 100;}

 }];

}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: where in your code you set localFindItDataController  of savedClearCloudDBClass. you seems only set it to  temp: tempClearCloudDBClass.localFindItDataController

Comment: Just answered my own question.  Forgot that to fire off notifications need to use manual setter methods.  AUGH!!!!  Once I included that it started firing off notifications.

Comment: The localFindItDataController is created in the initial panel and then passed through to this second panel.  It does work and in fact, the data in iCloud is successfully looped through and deleted.